# Image downsampling issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, image-editing

Hi so I'm trying to resize an image down so I can implement it into a Mailchimp Eblast. Original dimensions of the image are 5160x3840 at 5.3mb, and my desired dimensions are 564x300 (cropping to a different canvas size which is why dimensions aren't proportionate). Whenever I resize the image to the desired, downsampling occurs. Is there any way I could go around the downsampling and keep the resolution?

Original image and result are below:
[image]
[image]

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're throwing out 90% of the pixels, what makes you think this can be done without **actually** throwing out 90& of the pixels?

Comment: Downsampling is when you reduce the number of pixels, and pixels are the resolution - so the answer is no.

Comment: The poor quality in your second image is not from downsampling, but rather too much compression

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do that:

Choose the **Rectangular Selection Tool** > on the top options > **Style** > **Fixed Ratio** > put the width and height you want (564 X 300)

[image: select]

Do the frame on the image

[image: frame]

Menu Image > **Crop**

Menu File > **Save for Web**, choose the JPG type and put the width and height (564 x 300)

[image]

Comment: Why is this the "best way"? It still uses the same downsampling algorithms as when merely using `image Size`. `;)` I'm merely curious as to why you think this is better.

Comment: For me, save for web and devices gives always better results if it is for web. Maybe i should have put at the beginning of the answer, "The best way to me...", but I suppose that is implicit on each answer ;-)

Comment: If the quality in this approach is not good enough you could still try different qualities which you can choose in the drop down menu shown in the last image next to the new image size

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the image at 200% the desired size and then scale it down to 100%, and it should be sharp. Export the image as a .jpg at 1,128px x 600px, then import into mail chimp and change the image size to your desired size (564px 300px).